# Unhandled exception: Processing "data" event from proc stdout Error: Encoding not recognized: 'DOS-862' using cmake on vscode

Tags: c++11, cmake, visual-studio-code

I have a c++11 project build with cmake. The project compile well on visual studio 2017 and qt creator. However, when trying to compile it with vscode (with the CMake extension). I get the following strange error

> [proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" --build j:/LandSystems/Framework_2.0/Infrastructure/build --config Debug --target ALL_BUILD -- /m /property:GenerateFullPaths=true
>   [rollbar] Unhandled exception: Unhandled exception: Processing "data" event from proc stdout Error: Encoding not recognized: 'DOS-862' (searched as: 'dos862') {"data":{"type":"Buffer","data":[77,105,99,114,111,115,111,102,116,32,40,82,41,32,66,117,105,108,100,32,69,110,103,105,110,101,32,118,101,114,115,105,111,110,32,49,53,46,57,46,50,49,43,103,57,56,48,50,100,52,51,98,99,51,32,102,111,114,32,46,78,69,84,32,70,114,97,109,101,119,111,114,107,13,10,67,111,112,121,114,105,103,104,116,32,40,67,41,32,77,105,99,114,111,115,111,102,116,32,67,111,114,112,111,114,97,116,105,111,110,46,32,65,108,108,32,114,105,103,104,116,115,32,114,101,115,101,114,118,101,100,46,13,10,13,10]},"command":"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe","args":["--build","j:/LandSystems/Framework_2.0/Infrastructure/build","--config","Debug","--target","ALL_BUILD","--","/m","/property:GenerateFullPaths=true"]}

On my vscode cmake setting I selected the setting (to the cmake extension)

```
  "cmake.generator": "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64",
"cmake.configureArgs": [
    "-DUSE_CONAN=ON"
],
"cmake.cmakePath": "C:\\Program Files\\CMake\\bin\\cmake.exe",
"cmake.preferredGenerators":[
    "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64",
    "Ninja",
]
```

Any suggestions?